# how to build protocol buffer for iOS7?

Tags: ios7, protocol-buffers, xcode5

I want to rebuild protocol buffer staticlib in xcode5 ,
 download protocol buffer in http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list 
use autogen.sh , I get a configure file, can make and install on mac, I write a shell script try to build glib for iOS, as blow :

```
export ARCH=arm-apple-darwin10
export ARCH_PREFIX=${ARCH}-
export PLATFORM=iPhoneOS

export SDKVER=7.0
export DEVROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/${PLATFORM}.platform/Developer
export SDKROOT="$DEVROOT/SDKs/${PLATFORM}$SDKVER.sdk"

export Toolchains=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains
export XcodeClangBin="$Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin"
export XcodeCpp="$Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cpp"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$SDKROOT/usr/lib/pkgconfig:$DEVROOT/usr/lib/pkgconfig"
export AS="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/as"
export ASCPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/as"
export AR="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ar"
export RANLIB="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ranlib"
export CPP="$XcodeCpp"
export CXXCPP="$XcodeCpp"
export CC="$XcodeClangBin/clang"
export CXX="$XcodeClangBin/clang++"
export LD="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld"
export STRIP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/strip"

export CPPFLAGS="-pipe -no-cpp-precomp -I$SDKROOT/usr/include"
export CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -arch armv7s -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -fpascal-strings -no-cpp-precomp -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 --sysroot='$SDKROOT' -isystem $SDKROOT/usr/include"
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/${ARCH}/v6"
export LDFLAGS="--sysroot='$SDKROOT' -L$SDKROOT/usr/lib -L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/system"

./configure --host=${ARCH} --with-protoc=protoc --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=/tmp/protobuf/arm
make clean
make
make check
make install
```

When I run this script, return as :

```
#error Unsupported architecture
```

What can I do?

in ios6, xcode 4.6,  i can use this configure file to  build,    but in xcode5,  llvm-gcc has removed,  i use clang to replace it,  but is failed.

in ios6  ,  use this

```
export CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2"
export CXXCPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2"
```

Comment: I think that iOS runs on the ARM architecture.  If that's not supported with the code you've downloaded, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: in xcode 4.6,  ios6.1  ,  i can  use this configure file to build,  in xcode 5,  llvm-gcc has removed,  so i use clang to replace it,  but is failed.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small bash script that builds Protobuf for iOS 7.  The script can be found here.

https://gist.github.com/BennettSmith/7150245

This script will produce a proper build of Google Protobuf that supports the i386, armv7, armv7s, arm64 and x86_64 architectures.  It will produce a static library that is universal. It will also produce the protoc compiler for use on OS X.

Comment: An updated version of the script is now available that builds Google Protobuf 2.6.0 using Xcode 6.  This version includes a build for arm64, something that was not possible with the 2.5.0 version.  You can find the updated script here:  https://gist.github.com/BennettSmith/9487468ae3375d0db0cc

Answer (score 0):

remove those two lines

```
export CPP="$XcodeCpp"
export CXXCPP="$XcodeCpp"
```

then add -isysroot and -arch to

```
export CPPFLAGS="-pipe -no-cpp-precomp -I$SDKROOT/usr/include"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above script its understood that you are trying to build protobuf for different architectures like (armv7, armv7s ..etc) by default OSX build protobuf for 64 or 32 bit architecture. Which may not support in ios devices which have different cpu architecture.

**Steps to build protobuf for arm architecture:**

- Before running any configure scripts make sure you have installed
  proto buffer with default configuration using (./configure, make and
  make install).
- Check for protobuf version using "**protoc --version**" for confirmation. If protoc command not found check for environmental variable. This may happen when you didn't build protobuf in default location "/usr/local/bin/protoc". This step is important since we need to pass **protoc** in **--with-protoc** variable while configuring for different architecture.
- Go to the source where you unzipped your downloaded protobuffer and run the below script by having it in some ***.sh** file.

  > XCODEDIR=`xcode-select --print-path`
  >
  > OSX_SDK=$(xcodebuild -showsdks | grep macosx | sort | head -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}')
  >   IOS_SDK=$(xcodebuild -showsdks | grep iphoneos | sort | head -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}')
  >   SIM_SDK=$(xcodebuild -showsdks | grep iphonesimulator | sort | head -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}')
  >
  > MACOSX_PLATFORM=${XCODEDIR}/Platforms/MacOSX.platform
  >   MACOSX_SYSROOT=${MACOSX_PLATFORM}/Developer/${OSX_SDK}.sdk
  >
  > IPHONEOS_PLATFORM=${XCODEDIR}/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
  >   IPHONEOS_SYSROOT=${IPHONEOS_PLATFORM}/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk
  >
  > IPHONESIMULATOR_PLATFORM=${XCODEDIR}/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
  >   IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT=${IPHONESIMULATOR_PLATFORM}/Developer/SDKs/${SIM_SDK}.sdk
  >
  > PREFIX=**"your default location"**
  >
  > CC=clang
  >   CFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g -O0 -pipe -fPIC -fcxx-exceptions"
  >   CXX=clang
  >   CXXFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"
  >   LDFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"
  >   LIBS="-lc++ -lc++abi"
  >
  > ./configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0 --host=armv7-apple-darwin13.0.0 --with-protoc=protoc --disable-shared --prefix=${PREFIX} --exec-prefix=${PREFIX}/platform/armv7 "CC=${CC}" "CFLAGS=${CFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -arch armv7 -isysroot ${IPHONEOS_SYSROOT}" "CXX=${CXX}" "CXXFLAGS=${CXXFLAGS} -arch armv7 -isysroot ${IPHONEOS_SYSROOT}" LDFLAGS="-arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 ${LDFLAGS}" "LIBS=${LIBS}"
- Then run make and make install.
- Now you will have new libprotobuf.a static library in **${PREFIX}/platform/arvm7/lib** location which you need to have it in your xcode project for compiling protoc generated c++ file.